# Inserting data with one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: Products, Company, Type. Company and Types has one-to-many relationship with Products. 
[type model]

```
class Type extends BaseModel {
    public static $table = "type";
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function products() {
      return $this->has_many('Products');
    }
}
```

[company model]

```
class Company extends BaseModel {
    public static $table = "company";
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function products() {
        return $this->has_many('Products');
    }
}
```

[products model]

```
class Products extends BaseModel {
    public static $table = 'products';
    public static $timestamps = true;


    public function company() {
        return $this->belongs_to('Company');
    }

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongs_to('Type');
    }
}
```

In add_product route i have

```
$product = new Products($new_product); 
$company_id = $all_posts['company_id'];
$company = Company::find($company_id);
$company->products()->save($product);
$type_id = $all_posts['type'];
$type = Type::find($type_id);
$type->products()->save($product);
```

but when I try to insert data to db i get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I update both type_id and company_id in Products table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong, your products table should have product_id and type_id columns ? Just specify these values:

```
$new_product['company_id'] = $all_posts['company_id'];
$new_product['type_id'] = $all_posts['type'];
$product = new Products($new_product); 
$product->save();
```

You don't need to use Company and Type model to make relationship between them and a product. You can simply fill the ids.